# How to check if a value in the column gets updated?

Tags: sql-server

I have column named `HireDate` in table named `employeeInfo`. I simply need to check whenever the value or Date in the `HireDate` column gets updated using simple SQL script.

I am unable to write a simple script by which I can check it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "column gets updated" means? Do you need to know this inside a trigger? If not, what is supposed to be checked by this script and how it will be executed?

Comment: make sure to have a where clause; unless you plan to update the whole table with default value (then you dont need where clause). All depends on your business rules. Instead of UPDATE, first write out your query using SELECT statement to make sure desired result set is the one you wish to update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put trigger on the table. And if you want to execute your script when HireDate changed you can use "IF UPDATE(HireDate)". Check the following sample :

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_employeeInfo_CheckHireDate
   ON dbo.employeeInfo
   AFTER UPDATE--,INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (HireDate) 
    BEGIN
        --put your Update,Delete or Insert statments here
    END 
END
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your update. When user updates hire date then the script just shows that hire date updated.

Comment: It should be simple select script